# Separate express api database from server.js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server

I'm very newbie to Node.js and so is this question.

Im using this example please take a look at this link below.

https://github.com/sahat/newedenfaces-react/blob/master/server.js

In this server.js file the programmer is making call to

`mongoose.connect(config.database);`

`app.get('/api/characters', function(req, res, next) {}`

etc

all in server.js file

I want to keep everything cleaner

and just do the

`server.listen(app.get('port'), function() {}`

on `server.js` file and the rest of the things on some different file and import or stuff them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the express cli generator (https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html) to generate a project, you will see there how by default express separates api logic from the app.js (= your server.js file).

You have to declare in your app.js where specific logic for a controller is stored

```
var users = require('./routes/users');
```

And then which route should be used for that controller.

```
app.use('/users', users);
```

Then you can create a file there called users.js and put your logic there like here (**users.js**)

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* this is the route "/users/" as "/users" is defined in app.js to use that controller and / is defined here */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Next if you want to store youre DB stuff in an extra file you can create a models folder to declare your schema (if you use mongoose):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var schema = new Schema({
    firstName: {type: String, required: true},
    lastName: {type: String, required: true},
    email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', schema);
```

Then you can import it to your users routes files

```
var User = require('../models/user');
```